# Jquery one button updates multiple input fields on form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to update two input fields in a form when clicking one button. I actually had all the code right when using document.getElementById, but the form that I'm using strips the ID's I set away, so I can't use getbyid. If I know the form **field name**, how could I change my function to do the same thing? Please note that my form has more than two fields, including a submit button, so I don't want to update those.

This is what I used before (with the ID selector)
Html:

```
<input type="text" name="field-1" id="info1">
<input type="text" name="field" id="info2">   
<a  href="#" onclick="addTxt(['value1','value2'],'info','2')">Populate</a>
```

JS:

```
function addTxt(val, id,no)
  {
      var id = id;
      for(var i=1;i<=no;i++){
        document.getElementById(id+i).value = val[i-1];
      }

  }
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qwz47phx/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited with a much simpler and readable approach

```js
function addVal(obj) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent page scrolltop on anchor click
  $.each(obj, function(k, v) {
    $("input[name='"+ k +"']").val( v );
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="foo">
<input type="text" name="bar">   

<a href="#" onclick='addVal({foo:"Hello", "bar-baz":"World"})'>Populate</a>
```

Or with native JS (ES5+):

```js
function addVal(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(name) {
    document.querySelector('input[name="' + name + '"]').value = obj[name];    
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="foo">
<input type="text" name="bar">
<input type="text" name="name-with-dashes">   

<a  href="#" onclick='addVal({foo:"Hello", bar:"World", "name-with-dashes": "Works !"})'>Populate</a>
```

Comment: This works, but what if my field name has a dash in it?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH That was perfect, thank you so much!!! & Roko for the original answer too

Comment: @borie88 dashes? you use double quotes: `addVal({"foo-baz":"Hello", bar:"World"})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery `attribute=` selector to grab by name instead of ID.

```
function addTxt(val, id,no)
  {
      for(var i=1;i<=no;i++){
        var name = id+i;
        $("input[name='"+name+"']").val(val[i-1]);
  }

}
```

Please note that this function will be looking for names of info1, info2, info3, etc, just as your original script did. However, in the HTML, you have names of `info` and `info-1`. Either the names will have to be changed to fit the function, or the function can be slightly more intricate.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/qwz47phx/8/

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with IDs you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select inputs by name like this:

**JS:**

```
function addTxt(val, id, no) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= no; i++) {
    document.querySelector('input[name="' + id + i + '"]').value = val[i - 1];
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="info1" id="info1">
<input type="text" name="info2" id="info2">
<a href="#" onclick="addTxt(['id','num'],'info','2')">Populate</a>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/qwz47phx/6/

I hope this will help you.